# Why FPS Gauge in Xcode not usable for non-OpenGL ES or non-Metal App

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, frame-rate, metal

Xcode's FPS Gauge and GPU Report seems only usable for code directly using OpenGL ES and Metal(This pic is captured using non-OpenGL ES or non-Metal demo).

[image]

In my understanding, Even Core Graphics and Core Animation are built on OpenGL ES and Metal. Android can use **dumpsys gfxinfo** to get information for whatever app. What's wrong with my understanding?